# How to manage different time_zones in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone, timestamp

Attributes of users are `start_time`,`end_time` and `time_zone`.

I am saving only time not date and user time_zone
e.g

```
start_time => "09:00"
end_time => "02:00"
time_zone => "Samoa"
```

User is only called b/w given `start_time` and `end_time` according to given `time_zone`. How I check this?

My research , I found this

```
in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

I want to check that user is available or not according to its `start_time` and `end_time` based on `time_zone`

Comment: Is this time zone will be applicable for an entire application?

Comment: No no ......it depends on user time zeon

Comment: What is your question? Please, state the answerable question so that we could answer it.

Comment: I update my question.I want to check that user is available or not according to its start_time and end_time based on time_zone

Comment: Updated........................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server_tz = Time.zone # zone on server
server_now = server_tz.now # time on server right now

Time.use_zone(time_zone) do # ⇐ user’s time zone, 'Samoa'
  server_start, server_end = %i|start_time end_time|.map do |t|
    # ⇓ parse in user time zone and convert to server tz
    Time.zone.parse("#{Date.today} #{t}").in_time_zone(server_tz)
  end
  # ⇓ use case-triple-equal to check if time is in between
  (server_start..server_end) === server_now
end
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you ellaborate this

Comment: I have added comments in the code, explaining what’s happening on each step. What do you expect to be elaborated more?

Comment: why we get server time...our purpose is just to check user time

Comment: One cannot just _check_ user time, it should be checked/compared _against something_. Since you have users in different timezones, it would make sense to compare against kinda standard time. I have chosen the server time to be standard, since you shed no light on what your original intent is. Feel free to compare against whatever you want, I just showed a common pattern.

Comment: Thankuuuuu :) I understand this :)